# Compiler, library, or user error? Eigen::Array, GCC 12.1, "array subscript [...] is partly outside array bounds"

Tags: c++, arrays, vectorization, eigen, eigen3

After updating to GCC 12.1, I got a `array subscript ‘__m256d_u[0]’ is partly outside array bounds` error (or rather warning with `-Werror`) in my project, so I tried isolating the problem.

Here's an MWE, which I also put on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s53EKPcdW) (vector type is `__m512d_u` instead, but otherwise it's the same error):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using Eigen::Array;

Array<double, 3, 2> foo(){

    Array<double, 2, 2> a;
    a.setRandom();

    Array<double, 3, 2> b;
    b.col(0).tail(2) = a.col(1);
    // b.col(0).template tail<2>() = a.col(1);

    return b;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << foo() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Relevant compile options are `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -march=native`, and the error message notes `note: at offset [16, 24] into object ‘a’ of size 32`.

The error does not occur under the following circumstances:

- on GCC 11.3 or older,
- when removing `-march=native`
- when using `-O1` or below
- when replacing the line `b.col(0).tail(2) = a.col(1);` with `b.col(0).template tail<2>() = a.col(1);`

So it looks like GCC sees the 3x2 array and the 2x2 array, and doesn't realise that only two entries are accessed each.

My question now is: Who should this be reported to? GCC, Eigen? Or is it a user bug?

Bonus points for telling me what the `24` in the error note (`offset [16, 24]`) is. The `16` is the start, is the `24` the read size?

EDIT: Example can be further simplified by using `Array3d` and `Array2d`, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qvK744Eqb).

Comment: What line? Does it report anything else? Is the `using scalar = double;` relevant?

Comment: Check the godbolt link for all details. Line is #13, i.e. the one mentioned in the last bullet point. ```using scalar = double;``` is irrelevant, was just easier for me when creating an MWE from my project. I forgot about it when posting. Now I updated it, now the relevant line is #12

Comment: Just two thoughts: Check the bug reports of GCC and Eigen, maybe you find something in either one. In any case, have you tried using a memory debugger (Valgrind comes to mind) on it? That would be a big indicator that this is actually a bug or a false positive.

Comment: I reported the issue to GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106247 and Eigen: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2506

Comment: This family of warnings is very unreliable (see the number of bugs linked in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56456 for a start...), just ignore/disable them.

Comment: I made a very similar bug report that got instantly closed as a duplicate of a completely unrelated bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106939